# How to get particular value from responseText in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to PHP. I am currently working on AJAX, and in that I want a response from my file like this:

```
{'success':true,'id':234,'name':'X-ghfhg','type':'campaign','value':'fghfgh'}
```

This is in responseText. I want to use the `id` of that response. I tried `JSON.Parse` Method but it is not working.

Here is my AJAX:

```
$('#ButtonAddHeader').click(function(){
//  addEmailHeader();
        var HeaderName = $('#HeaderName').val();
        var EmailType = $('#emailType').val();
        var HeaderValue = $('#HeaderValue').val();

        if(HeaderName == "X-" || HeaderValue == "" )
            {
            $('#addHeaderMessage').text("Please fill in all the required fields below").addClass('text-error');
            }
            else
            {
        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url:CONTROLLER_URL+'snippet_addEmailHeader',
            data : { HeaderName : HeaderName, EmailType : EmailType, HeaderValue : HeaderValue },   
             complete: function(response){
            // Handle the complete event
            console.log(response.responseText);

            },
        });
});
```

Comment: `response.responseText.id` ?

Comment: i try it but it is given undefined value

Comment: `console.log(response)` and post the results of it.

Comment: readyState
 4
 
responseText
 "{'success':true,'id':24...all','value':'hfghfgh'}"
 
status
 200
 
statusText
 "OK"
 
abort
 function()
 
always
 function()
 
complete
 function()
 
done
 function()
 
error
 function()
 
fail
 function()
 
getAllResponseHeaders
 function()
 
getResponseHeader
 function()
 
overrideMimeType
 function()
 
pipe
 function()
 
progress
 function()
 
promise
 function()
 
setRequestHeader
 function()
 
state
 function()
 
statusCode
 function()
 
success
 function()
 
then
 function()

Comment: No it returns blank value

Comment: How are you generating the output from PHP? You should be outputting is like `echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'id' => 234, 'name' => 'X-ghfhg', 'type' => 'campaign', 'value' => 'fghfgh'));`

Comment: it is in codeigniter and i have no permission to access that controller file from where data comes, i just use that response data anyway how.

Comment: `response.id` should work. According to your console.log, I see `'id':24...all'` that will cause a syntax error because the value is not surrounded by quotes, missing single quote in front of 24. If it was just `'id':24` it would work fine because its an integer. How are you not getting an error?

Comment: i am not getting error , just return blank value if i wrote response.id

Comment: did you show the whole json response?

Comment: Thank You for your support

i take data in array form responseText[1] format and then concating that data and make it string and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Define a `success` callback in your ajax declaration.  The parameter to that callback function (`json` in this example) is then usable as a JSON object:

`success: function(json) {
    // You're looking for: json.id
}`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url:CONTROLLER_URL+'snippet_addEmailHeader',
            data : { HeaderName : HeaderName, EmailType : EmailType, HeaderValue : HeaderValue },
 success: function(data) {
        var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(mydata['id']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your json like-
`info[{'success':true,'id':234,'name':'X-ghfhg','type':'campaign','value':'fghfgh'}];`
then,

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: CONTROLLER_URL+'snippet_addEmailHeader',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data)
                {
                  var objJSON = JSON.parse(data);
                  var classinfo = objJSON.info[0];
                  var id = val(classinfo.id);
                  alert(id);

                }                     
            }
        });
```

Comment: please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778675/morris-line-chart