# Morris line chart

Tags: codeigniter, charts, linechart, morris.js

i am using morris line chart in my application,

Here everything is complete but on x axis i wrote 1 then it display 1910 but i want there current month and date not year. means i want date in place of list of year.

Here is my code:

```
Morris.Line({
      element: 'line-example',
      data: [

        { time: '1', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '2', a: 0,  b: 0 },
        { time: '3', a: 0,  b: 0 },
        { time: '4', a: 0,  b: 0 },
        { time: '5', a: 0,  b: 0 },
        { time: '6', a: 0,  b: 0 },
        { time: '7', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '8', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '9', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '10', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '11', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '12', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '13', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '14', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '15', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '16', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '17', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '18', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '19', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '20', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '21', a: 0, b: 1 },
        { time: '22', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '23', a: 1, b: 0 },
        { time: '24', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '25', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '26', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '27', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '28', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '29', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '30', a: 0, b: 0 },
        { time: '31', a: 0, b: 0 },


      ],
      xkey: 'time',
      ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
      labels: ['Subscriptions', 'Unsubscriptions'],
      lineColors:['#0176CC','#FF9701'],


    });
```

Comment: current month & date keep in one variable and pass that variable value

Comment: Thank you is i pass that variable to all line or only one.? Please suggest me some of code i am new in this chart.